Usage of queue.xml in Magento 2.4.x?
In my RabbitMQ implementation, I've been working with the following XML files:

communication.xml
queue_topology.xml
queue_consumer.xml
queue_publisher.xml

However, I recently came across another file, queue.xml.
Can anyone explain what the purpose of queue.xml is and how it fits into the RabbitMQ setup?

The queue.xml file has been deprecated since Magento Commerce version 2.2. For detailed information, refer to the official documentation at https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/message-queues/migration/.
In summary, the configuration previously found in queue.xml has been distributed across multiple files, including queue_consumer.xml, queue_topology.xml, and queue_publisher.xml.
